Blazor Server Routing
I am using Blazor Server. We have organizations, and within each organization, there are products, attributes, and other pages.
When working with products or any part of the module, an organization must be selected. I am wondering how we can include the organization ID in the URL. Is it possible to add it in the main component and check if the user doesn't have the ID in the URL, then the default organization ID is added to the URL?
A sample URL could be:
https://dle.com/app/organizations/48789/products/770631
https://dle.com/app/organizations/48789/attribute/770631
https://dle.com/app/organizations/48789/foo/770631
https://dle.com/app/organizations/48789/bar/770631

Of course, I can add the organization ID to all the pages, but I don't think this is a good approach. Please let me know if anyone can help me.
I added the organization id to few pages like this:
/{OrganizationId}/products/{ProductId}
but adding it in all pages is not a good approach according to my understanding

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Can you accept cascading values?
